# access fields in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, web

I am having trouble accessing fields(variables) in a function definition. My question is with this code:

```
<script>
  function test(){ var book= [];}
  var arrs = test();
  alert(arrs.book);
</script>
```

It gives me 'undefined', why? I would expect it to be an empty value. Is there any way I can access this `book` array variable in `arrs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrs` is undefined because `test()` doesn't return anything.  All the function does is locally declare a variable and then end, so the local variable just falls out of scope and nothing happens.

Based on the usage, it looks like you want your function to maybe return an object?:

```
function test() {
    return { book: [] };
}
```

Or maybe the function should itself construct an object and you meant to call it with `new`?:

```
function test() {
    this.book = [];
}
var arrs = new test();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Carcigenicate said, you are missing the return statement inside test().

```
function test(){ 
    var book= [];
    // missing return...
    return book;
}
var arrs = test();
alert(arrs);
```

Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// old way
function Test1() {
  this.books = ['t1']
}

var t1 = new Test1()

alert(t1.books)


//es6 class
class T2 {
  constructor() {
    this.books = ['t2']
  }
}

var t2 = new T2()
alert(t2.books)

// plain object
var t3 = {
  books: ['t3']
}
alert(t3.books)

// static field 
function T4() {}
T4.prototype.books = []

var t4a = new T4(),
  t4b = new T4()
t4a.books.push('t4')
alert(t4b.books)
```